# How to open windows explorer when I click a button?

Tags: windows, delphi, explorer

I have a form in a Delphi project. There is a button on the form. When the user clicks the button, I want it to open Windows Explorer.

What code will I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 29):

Well in case you need to select some particular file in explorer I have the following function which I use

```
procedure SelectFileInExplorer(const Fn: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', 'explorer.exe',
    PChar('/select,"' + Fn+'"'), nil, SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

and you can call it :

```
SelectFileInExplorer('C:\Windows\notepad.exe');
```

EDIT: As mentioned ShellAPI must be added to your uses list

Comment: Shouldn't `PWideChar` be used instead of `PChar`?

Comment: "explore" works as a verb for folders, and nil does the default (which is Windows explorer for folders). The traditional name for this function is OpenFileDefaultViewer(), which you can google (meant more for "open" than "explore"). It should work on any file type too, based on what's mapped in the registry for the file extension (eg. readme.txt --> notepad). Be careful of the Application assumption; if there's no window (e.g. command-line, or DLL) then you can pass 0 as an invalid handle. The handle is more about Windows managing the active window and window ownership I think.

Answer (score 13):

Building on what Mason Wheeler said: you can also pass in a directory as an argument, to get the window to open to a non-default location:

```
uses
  ShellAPI;

...

  ShellExecute(Application.Handle,
    nil,
    'explorer.exe',
    PChar('c:\'), //wherever you want the window to open to
    nil,
    SW_NORMAL     //see other possibilities by ctrl+clicking on SW_NORMAL
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, 'explorer.exe', nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

You'll need to add `ShellAPI` to your **uses** clause.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx, ShellExecute also supports the 'explore' verb, which 'explores' a folder specified by lpFile, so this should work:

```
ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'explore', '.', nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

In firemonkey, to open the explorer selecting a file:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.ShellAPI,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Platform.Win;

procedure OpenExplorerSelectingFile(const AFileName: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(WindowHandleToPlatform(Application.MainForm.Handle).Wnd, 'open', 'explorer.exe', PChar('/select,"' + AFilename + '"'), nil, SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509294/9134997) there is a difference if you want to

- select the folder in explorer
- or open it and show its content with explorer

I use these functions:

```
uses Winapi.ShellAPI;

procedure SelectFileOrFolderInExplorer(const sFilename: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', 'explorer.exe',
    PChar(Format('/select,"%s"', [sFilename])), nil, SW_NORMAL);
end;

procedure OpenFolderInExplorer(const sFoldername: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar(sFoldername), nil, nil, sw_Show);
end;

procedure ExecuteFile(const sFilename: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar(sFilename), nil, nil, sw_Show);
end;
```

Usage:

```
SelectFileOrFolderInExplorer('C:\Windows');
SelectFileOrFolderInExplorer('C:\Windows\notepad.exe');
OpenFolderInExplorer('C:\Windows');
ExecuteFile('C:\MyTextFile.txt');
```