# Open explorer from a string delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to open Windows Explorer from within Delphi with a directory I got from the user. This directory is saved as a string.
When I use the following code it will not accept it. I have to physically type it in.

```
sDir : string;

procedure OpenDirectoryClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShellExecute(Handle,nil,sDir,nil,nil,sw_Show);
end;
```

The above code does not work

```
sDir : string;

procedure OpenDirectoryClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShellExecute(Handle,nil,'C:\Windows',nil,nil,sw_Show);
end;
```

The above code does work

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third parameter should be casted into PChar, so please try this:

```
ShellExecute(Handle,nil,PChar(sDir),nil,nil,sw_Show);
```

Hope this helps :)

By the way: it's clever not to count on default Windows API behaviour and specify the second parameter as 'open', not as nil - just in case ;)

Comment: Nah my delphi wont even run with this. Could it be that my delphi is the 2006 version?

Comment: Actually, it's better to **not** supply `open`, and to allow Windows to decide the default behavior when that's what you want. That's been discussed here many times. If you want the **default** behavior, leave the second parameter nil and **get** the default behavior. Many types of software don't register `open` as a default.

Comment: Well, the author wrote: "i am trying to open windows explorer..." - so  'open' seems to be expected behaviour, isn't it? :)

Comment: Um, no. What if the default is `explore`? As I said, if you want the **default** behavior, don't tell Windows to do anything and you'll get it. Why guess what **default** might be? But I'll let Microsoft explain - read the documentation for ShellExecute on MSDN for yourself. :-)

Comment: To open an explorer window, you are supposed to use the `'explore'` verb, not the `'open'` verb, especially if `'explore'` is not the default. If you know the exact behavior you want to invoke, then don't rely on default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To open/show/select a file or folder in the Windows Explorer I use these functions:

```
uses Winapi.ShellAPI;

procedure SelectFileOrFolderInExplorer(const sFilename: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', 'explorer.exe',
    PChar(Format('/select,"%s"', [sFilename])), nil, SW_NORMAL);
end;

procedure OpenFolderInExplorer(const sFoldername: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar(sFoldername), nil, nil, sw_Show);
end;

procedure ExecuteFile(const sFilename: string);
begin
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar(sFilename), nil, nil, sw_Show);
end;
```

Usage:

```
SelectFileOrFolderInExplorer('C:\Windows\notepad.exe');
SelectFileOrFolderInExplorer('C:\Windows');
OpenFolderInExplorer('C:\Windows');
ExecuteFile('C:\MyTextFile.txt');
```

**Note:** The content of `OpenFolderInExplorer()` and `ExecuteFile()` is basically the same. Windows decides to open a folder with the explorer and a text file with notepad.